# Avg Time difference in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a function to find average time difference in the standard time format in my sql.

Comment: You should accept answers for your questions by clicking the hollow check next to your favorite answer for each question.  You can see all of your questions by clicking `rupa` at the top of the screen.  This will encourage people to give you more answers in the future.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`timestampdiff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to find the difference between two times.

I'm not sure what you mean by "average," though. Average across the table? Average across a row?

If it's the table or a subset of rows:

```
select
    avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, startTimestamp, endTimestamp)) as avgdiff
from
    table
```

The `avg` function works like any other aggregate function, and will respond to `group by`. For example:

```
select
    col1,
    avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, startTimestamp, endTimestamp)) as avgdiff
from
    table
group by col1
```

That will give you the average differences for each distinct value of `col1`.

Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for response Eric

TIMEDIFF also gives me time difference. But want to find out the average time difference

Comment: @rupa: So not the averages I posted, then?

Answer (score 13):

In order to get actual averages in the standard time format from mysql I had to convert to seconds, average, and then convert back:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeA, timeB))))
```

If you don't convert to seconds, you get an odd decimal representation of the minutes that doesn't really make any sense (to me).

Answer (score 11):

What I like to do is a

```
SELECT count(*), AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end,start)))
FROM
  table
```

Gives the number of rows as well...

Comment: You can actually just use `AVG` on the `TIMEDIFF` without `TIME_TO_SEC` which will give you `HH:MM:SS` average. eg.
`SELECT count(*), AVG(TIMEDIFF(end,start))
FROM
  table`

Comment: @George No, this doesnt work as you say. I get some weird values

Comment: I second pauljeba's comment - `AVG(TIMEDIFF)` returns junk (or at least not `HH:MM:SS` format).

Answer (score 5):

I was curious if `AVG()` was accurate or not, the way that `COUNT()` actually just approximates the value (["this value is an approximation"](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46422)).  After all, let's review the average formula: `average = sum / count`.  So, knowing that the count is accurate is actually really important for this formula!

After testing multiple combinations, it definitely seems like `AVG()` works and is a great approach. You can calculate yourself to see if it's working with...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS count,
    AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, OrigDateTime, LastDateTime)) AS avg_average,
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, OrigDateTime, LastDateTime)) / (select COUNT(id) FROM yourTable) as calculated_average,
    AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LastDateTime,OrigDateTime))) as timediff_average,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LastDateTime, OrigDateTime)))) as date_display
FROM yourTable
```

Sample Results:

```
             count: 441000
       avg_average: 5045436.4376
calculated_average: 5045436.4376
  timediff_average: 5045436.4376
      date_display: 1401:30:36
```

Seems to be pretty accurate!

This will return:

- `count`: The count.
- `avg_average`: The average based on `AVG()`. (Thanks to Eric for their answer on this!)
- `calculated_average`: The average based on `SUM()/COUNT()`.
- `timediff_avg`: The average based on `TIMEDIFF()`. (Thanks to Andrew for their answer on this!)
- `date_display`: A nicely-formatted display version. (Thanks to C S for their answer on this!)