# How do I average MySQL result set

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query that tells me the difference between status change entries:

```
SELECT 
    t1.`TRACKID` AS TicketNumber,
    TIMEDIFF(t2.`date`, t1.`date`) AS Difference
FROM
    hesk_history t1
    JOIN hesk_history t2 ON t2.`TRACKID` = t1.`TRACKID` AND t1.`Action` = 'Created' AND (t2.`Action` = 2)
```

Gives me the following result set:

```
TicketNumber    Difference
2013-08-12-36   410:21:25
2013-06-12-91   00:01:22
2013-08-12-50   00:00:26
```

How do I then AVG this result set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avg Time difference in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231122/avg-time-difference-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp
so in your case

SELECT 
    AVG(t1.`TRACKID` AS TicketNumber,
    TIMEDIFF(t2.`date`, t1.`date`)) AS Difference
FROM
    hesk_history t1
    JOIN hesk_history t2 ON t2.`TRACKID` = t1.`TRACKID` AND t1.`Action` = 'Created' AND (t2.`Action` = 2)

Comment: This does not provide me with any result set.  I get an error code 1064.  I am looking for the result set, then the avg below that.